# Esperar en selenium hasta que un input de tipo radio sea clickeable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto el cual requiere que espere a que un input de tipo radio sea clickeable, como bien lo dice el título.
El motivo por el cual tengo que esperar, es porque me sale un StaleElementReferenceException al intentar buscarlo y darle click.
**Mi idea *NO* es agregarle un time.sleep, ni una espera implicita**
Intente probar con:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@name='prestadores[1][estado]'])[1]")))
```

Pero da un TimeoutException.
Alguien sabe como esperar dinámicamente a que un elemento de tales propiedades sea clickeable?

Último detalle: **El elemento existe y no hay problemas al localizarlo**.

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar un tipo de espera llamado explicita que permita esperar X tiempo hasta que aparesca el elemento, si aparece antes se sale antes.

```
    public static boolean visualizarObjeto(WebElement elementName, int timeout) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Valida si Es visible el elemento a validar.");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverContext.getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(timeout));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementName));
        System.out.println("Es visible el elemento a validar: " + elementName.getText());
        System.out.println("==============================================");
        System.out.println();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception var3) {
        System.out.println("No es visible el elemento a validar.");
        return false;
    }
}
```